# Return None if can't find text

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying paste information on monsters from a pdf into a group of cells in Excel and format it a certain way.  These monsters have various abilities like resistances, vulnerabilities, and immunities to damage.  if they don't have them nothing is listed for it. I have a macro that searches for keyword in the cell (i.e. Resistances) and outputs it to a specific cell.  If that keyword is not listed then it throws an error.  There is a formula iferror that can return none if there is no information but I don't see how it could search multiple cells.

My code works correctly when the search word is in the cells but gives an error when it is missing.

```
Const Challenge As String = "Challenge"

Dim CR_Ratting As String

CR_Ratting = Range("b1:b45").Find(Challenge, , xlValues, xlPart)

Range("i16") = CR_Ratting
```

When | Challenge 1/2 (100 XP) | is input into a cell in the range of B1 to B45 it will place the contents of the cell into I16.  If the word Challenge is not found in that range it gives an error.

Comment: Try this line instead `If Not CR_Ratting Is Nothing Then Range("i16") = CR_Ratting`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
Const Challenge As String = "Challenge"

Dim CR_Ratting As Range '<< not String

Set CR_Ratting = Range("b1:b45").Find(Challenge, , xlValues, xlPart)

If not CR_Ratting Is Nothing Then Range("i16") = CR_Ratting '<< test before assigning value
```

Comment: When I use that it always returns a blank.

Comment: Sounds like it’s not finding anything

Comment: Yeah but for the original form, if it is there it can read it.

Comment: If I remove the not and make a constant string none and add else to put the correct text in there.